# SQL CASE With User Defined Parameters

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been tasked with making several reports that allow a user to:

1. Enter nothing and get all related data
2. Filter one or more pieces of data (separated by commas)

I thought using a CASE statement would be simple for this so I did the following in a WHERE:

```
SomeTable.SomeField IN (CASE 

WHEN :P_ITEM_CLAUSE IS NULL THEN SomeTable.SomeField

WHEN INSTR(:P_ITEM_CLAUSE,',') > 0 THEN ''''||TO_CHAR(replace(:P_ITEM_CLAUSE,',', ''''||', '||''''))||''''

ELSE TO_CHAR(:P_ITEM_CLAUSE) END)
```

The first and third conditions work as expected, but the second condition returns no data. I also tested the second condition separately using DUAL and was able to get all values I entered in the parameter. This is an Oracle server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `like`.  Something like this:

```
where :P_ITEM_CLAUSE is null or
      ',' || :P_ITEM_CLAUSE  || ',' like '%,' || SomeTable.SomeField || ',%'
```

Note that the resulting query will not be able to use an index on `SomeField`.